# Twitter module has no object 'trends'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
import tweepy
import json

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

twitter_api = tweepy.API(auth)
# I made a dict of different countries and their WOE_ID...

PLACE_WOE_ID = country_id[country]
place_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=PLACE_WOE_ID)
```

Everytime I run my code I am getting the following error. I checked other posts on stackoverflow regarding twitter api but I haven't found a solution yet.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Documents/twipgm.py", line 44, in <module>
    place_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=PLACE_WOE_ID)
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'trends'
```

Comment: it's [`trends_place()`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/3.7.0/api.html#API.trends_place) not `trends.place()`

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 2):

There is no method like

> place()

in tweepy documentation.

```
place_trends = twitter_api.trends_place(..)
```

Should solve your problem, I strongly suggest you to check this [docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/3.7.0/api.html#API.trends_available).

Answer (score 0):

Note that Tweepy 4.0 version has renamed this method to `.get_place_trends()`.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://www.ezzeddinabdullah.com/posts/get-trending-tweets-python-tweepy) to get some recent updates on Tweepy >4.0 use cases.